# How to use bootstrap spinner in a template before the webpage is fully loaded using setTimeout()?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I wanted the Bootstrap 4 spinner to appear if there is any delay in loading the template of an angular component. How to do it?

How can I make it disappear after the template is fully loaded? Should I use `setTimeout()`, if so then how would I implement it?

Comment: Templates in Angular are not loaded async. Are you referring to AngularJS?

Comment: I'd create an overlay component with a spinner and make it listen to some (observable, promise, whatever) event

Comment: fully loading meaning, are you getting data behind the scenes? Can you add some code?

Comment: i fetch data from an api.the data loads faster but sometimes there may be latency hence to be on safer side in terms of user-friendliness of website can i add a bootstrap spinner till the api is loaded

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your using full Angular and not angularJS, There's no need for setTimeout(). Something like this is all you'd need:

```
<div class="page" *ngIf="apiDataObject; else loading">
    // rest of component
</div>
<ng-template #loading>
   // whatever spinner/loading indicator you want
</ng-template>
```

Comment: A big thank you for helping me in gaining this knowledge about spinners and resolving this issue. Your suggestion was really helpful.